# rails carrierwave object is nil when using cache_stored_file! with fog & s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog) about how to recreate and reprocess your files stored on fog.

And here is my attempt to be able to recreate version my image using carrierwave and upload it to AWS:

```
product_image = ProductImage.first
product_image.process_image_upload = true
product_image.image.cache_stored_file!
product_image.image.retrieve_from_cache!(product_image.image.cache_name) 
product_image.image.recreate_versions!(:pattern)
product_image.save!
```

but until this line:

```
product_image.image.cache_stored_file!
```

give me an error. it said:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

anybody has the same experience for me? thanks in advance

Comment: please add the full trace